# solr XML parser Exception

Tags: solr, nutch

I have configured the solr search engine. I followed the steps from [Here](http://tgels.com/wiki/en/Solr_and_Nutch_Steps)

I am getting following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;systemId: solrres:/solrconfig.xml; lineNumber: 813; columnNumber: 19; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
  at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:148)
  at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:86)
  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:120)
  at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:589)
  ... 11 more
used by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: solrres:/solrconfig.xml; lineNumber: 813; columnNumber: 19; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

I checked in configuration file. the error is at

```
<str name="mm"> 2<-1 5<-2 6<90% </str>
```

How can i configure the same, if i avoid to configure above what will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `< >` are xml characters, parsing would fail.
You would need to use `&gt;` and `&lt;` for > & < respectively in the Solr Config xml file.

e.g. `<str name="mm">4 &lt; 100%</str>`

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing '<' with '`&lt;`'. After changing that, the configuration will be 2`&lt;`-1 5`&lt;`-2 6`&lt;`90%